# Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content android exception

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I know this question is already been asked on stack but i tried all the solutions but of no use.Still i'm getting the same below error

**Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content**

below is code-

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        **requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);**  
        setContentView(R.layout.info);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
     }
```

I tried many links like given below-
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=requestFeature%28%29+must+be+called+before+adding+content

is there any solution???

Comment: yeah..i tried that one also..but no use..

Comment: Did you added any style **Theme** for your application??

Comment: i haven't used any theme for the current activity for which i'm trying to change window title

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.info);

     }
```

Comment: i have done this one also but no use

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this..

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);     
    setContentView(R.layout.info);        
 }
```